# Initialization of the Kalman Filter

Tags: maximum-likelihood, kalman-filter

I would like to try out different initialization procedures of the Kalman Filter in order to see if it effects the estimation paths of the state variables.

One way of initializing is to use the first observation in ML to obtain estimates of the initial state, and then impose those estimates before continuing as normal for T = 2,...N.

However, I am confused on how to tackle this issue.

The log-likehood code:

```
kalman.log.likelihood <- function(xi.tm1tm1, P.tm1tm1, F, Q, A, H, R, y, x) {
  T <- dim(y)[1]
  n <- dim(y)[2]
  ll.vec <- matrix(NA,T,1)
  ll.cum <- 0
  xi.tt <- xi.tm1tm1
  P.tt  <- P.tm1tm1   

  for (t in 1:T){

    xi.ttm1 <- F %*% xi.tt

    P.ttm1 <- F %*% P.tt %*% t(F) + Q

    prediction.error <- (as.vector(y[t,]) - as.vector(t(A) %*% as.vector(x[t,])) - as.vector(t(H) %*% xi.ttm1))

    HPHR <- t(H) %*% P.ttm1 %*% H + R

    ll.vec[t] <- drop(-(n / 2) * log(2 * atan(1) * 4) - 0.5 * log(det(HPHR))
                      -0.5 * prediction.error %*% solve(HPHR, prediction.error))

    ll.cum <- ll.cum + ll.vec[t]

    xi.tt <- xi.ttm1 + P.ttm1 %*% H %*% solve(HPHR, prediction.error)

    P.tt  <- P.ttm1 - P.ttm1 %*% H %*% solve(HPHR, t(H) %*% P.ttm1)
  }
  return(list("ll.vec"=ll.vec,"ll.cum"=ll.cum))
}
```

y and x are the data-vectors; F,Q, etc. are coefficient matrices, specified somewhere else; xi is the state-vector with it's covariance matrix P. Overal notation is consistent with Hamilton's (1994).

The goal is to obtain initial estimates for xi.00 and P.00.

Thanks!

PS. Are there any other frequently used methods to initialize the KF?

Comment: Hmm. Spacecraft (for which the Kalman filter was originally designed) have the lovely property of being really easy to locate prior to launch.

Comment: @Ingolifs Hi, the application is this case are time-series.